# Transferring funds from a contract to an account using adresses

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, ethereumjs

I had been trying for a long to transfer the complete fund with one of my contracts to a specific account. But nothing seems to be working.

```
pragma solidity >= 0.4.22;

contract reg{
  address owner;
  uint256 regFee = 2 ether;
  address[] private registered;
  uint a = 0;

  mapping (address => uint256) public balance;

  constructor() public{
    owner = msg.sender;
    regFee = 2 ether;
  }

  event registeration(address indexed _to);

  // function register() public{
  //     balance[(msg.sender)] -= 2 ether;
  //     balance[msg.sender] += 2 ether;
  //     emit registeration(msg.sender);
  // }

  function () payable external{
    balance[(msg.sender)] -= 2 ether;
    balance[address(this)] += 2 ether;
    registered.push(msg.sender);
    a++;
    emit registeration(msg.sender);
  }

  function list() public view returns(address, address, address){
    return (registered[0], registered[1], registered[2]);
  }
}
```

this the complete contract.

Another contract I want to write is to select one of the

> registered[0], registered[1], registered[2]

and transfer all fund of *contract reg* to contract *subm*. Following is the code to subm .

```
pragma solidity >= 0.4.22;

import "./Untitled.sol";

contract subm{
  address winner;
  reg public regi;

  mapping (address => uint256) public balance;

  function submissions() public{
    if (winner == address(0)){
        winner = msg.sender;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

Someone kindly help, confused due to new syntaxes.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum StackExchange! Ether transfers happen automatically when calling a `payable` function - you don't need to modify any balances. Otherwise, I'm a bit confused what you are trying to achieve - can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do?

Comment: hello @la

i will be directly using metamsk to transfer ethers to `contract reg` , then I will be having another `payable` contract `subm`. 
So basically i want to transfer funds collected in an instance `contract reg` to `contract subm` , so that I can use another contract to use those ethers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you have one contract `reg` which collects Ethers from users and another contract `subm` where you want to forward the collected Ethers.

I guess you also had some other ideas for functionality but I wasn't sure what you were trying to accomplish with those.

So here is one possible super-simple example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract Reg {
    mapping (address => uint256) public userBalances;
    address payable otherContr;

    constructor(address payable otherContrAddr) public {
        otherContr = otherContrAddr;
    }

    function() payable external  {
        userBalances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function transferToOtherContr() public {
        otherContr.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

}

contract Subm {
    function() payable external { 
        // Do something with the sent Ethers
    }
}
```

This way whatever Ethers are sent to `Reg` gets recorded in a variable called `userBalances`. Note that this record keeping is purely optional and for internal reasons if you need such. Then there's another function `transferToOtherContr` which simply sends all Ethers in the contract to the other contract `otherContr`. The contract `otherContr (Subm)` needs to be created contract `Reg` so you can give its contract address in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Lauri, with few, headbangs I was able to create a contract that helped me. Though few things it had too similar to your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped you. If a given answer solves your problem, please mark is the correct answer. And if a given answer is helpful, you can indicate it with giving it a point with the arrows.